# how to use "FindBarcodesInUIImage"?

Tags: iphone, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am developing `Barcode scanner` application for iPhone.

Library: `RedLaser`

Just I want to scan the barcode from the existing image, not from camera.
I didn't get any documentation to call `FindBarcodesInUIImage` method manually.

Can I get any sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this snippet [from the documentation](http://redlaser.com/developers/documentation/ios/using-the-sdk/) help?

> This method analyses a given image and returns information on any barcodes discovered in the image. It is intended to be used in cases where the user already has a picture of a barcode (in their photos library, for example) that they want to decode. This method performs a thorough check for all barcode symbologies we support, and is not intended for real-time use.
>
> When scanning barcodes using this method, you cannot (and need not) specify a scan orientation or active scan region; the entire image is scanned in all orientations. Nor can you restrict the scan to particular symbol types. If such a feature is absolutely necessary, you can implement it post-scan by filtering the result set.
>
> FindBarcodesInUIImage operates synchronously, but can be placed in a thread. Depending on image size and processor speed, it can take several seconds to process an image.

Comment: I didn't understand how to do.. I have tried in many ways.. but it failed. could you please give an example..

Answer (score 0):

```
void ScanImageForBarcodes(UIImage *inputImage)
{
    NSSet *resultSet = FindBarcodesInUIImage(inputImage);

    // Print the results
    NSLog(@"%@", resultSet);
}
```

If the SDK did not find any barcodes in the image, the log message will be (null). Otherwise, it will be something like:

```
{(
    (0x19e0660) Code 39: 73250110 -- (1 finds)
)}
```

This log message indicates a found set containing one item, a Code 39 barcode with the value "73250110".

Remember that the SDK is not guaranteed to find barcodes in an image. Even if an image contains a barcode, the SDK might not be able to read it, and you will receive no results.